# Java paypal integeration (Website Payments Pro)

Tags: java, paypal, website-payment-pro

I am working on java, spring web based project where i want to integrate PayPal using Website Payments Pro.

**Using "Website Payments Pro" i want to implement**

**Direct Payment:** enables you to accept both debit and credit cards directly from your sit. (using without pay pal account)

**Express Checkout:** enables you to accept payments from PayPal accounts in addition to debit and credit cards.

Any work tutorials for above both implementions ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've implemented Website Payments Pro on our eCommerce site.  All of the documentation can be found on PayPal's website [here](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_WPWebsitePaymentsPro).

In particular, check out the [Integration Guide](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_documentation#wpp) PDF to get you started.  Also helpful is Name-Value Pair API (the easiest way to use their API's), the sample code, and the Sandbox User's Guide for testing.